# Toggle using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function toggleMenu() {
    var thisMenu = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    if( thisMenu.style.display == 'block' ) {
        thisMenu.style.display = 'none';
    } else { 
        thisMenu.style.display = 'block';
    }
    return thisMenu;
}

<li class="NavLinks test2" id="menuItem">
    <a onclick="toggleMenu('menuItem');">Tutorial</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>     
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</script>
```

***description*******************

onClick on Tutorial hide's the submenu items but if I click on Tutorial and hover over submenu items and hovers out the item list item are not hiding. Please let me know if my code needs to modify.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `id` argument.

Change

```
function toggleMenu(){
```

to

```
function toggleMenu(id){
```

Comment: I have pasted wrongly. i have tried your code as well. List iteams are not hidding.

Comment: You sure it's not working? I just tested it and it works. It takes more than one click initially though. Change the if condition to this and try `if(thisMenu.style.display == '' || thisMenu.style.display == 'block')`

Comment: After clicking the Tutorial google and yahoo i can see it but if you just hover over google and move your cursor out of google, google and yahoo wont be hidden

Comment: They are not hiding on mouseout because you've only assigned the onclick event. To show/hide on mouseover and out, you have to add the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to the inner `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `toggleMenu` function does not take any arguments. Also your html is inside of your script tag

```
<script>
function toggleMenu( id ){
  var thisMenu = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  if( thisMenu.style.display == 'block' ) {
    thisMenu.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    thisMenu.style.display = 'block';
  }
  return thisMenu ;
}
</script>
<li class="NavLinks test2" id="menuIteam">
<a onclick="toggleMenu('menuIteam');">Tutorial</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>     
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I have pasted wrongly. I tried the below code as well:       <script>
function toggleMenu( id ){
  var thisMenu = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  if( thisMenu.style.display == 'block' ) {
    thisMenu.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    thisMenu.style.display = 'block';
  }
  return thisMenu ;
}
</script>
<li class="NavLinks test2" id="menuIteam">
<a onclick="toggleMenu('menuIteam');">Tutorial</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>     
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
</li>