# How could I write toggle functionality manually?

Tags: javascript

I need to write javascript toggle functionality by manually.
Please, help to understand how could I do it.

Comment: What do you have thus far, what have you tried. What research did you do?

Comment: @elclanrs, please post that as an answer. Conceptual answer to conceptual question.

Comment: lol, I'm not even sure that was the case, deleted the comment sadly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [toggle using pure javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355683/toggle-using-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `function` for toggle

```
function toggle(obj) { // obj is element's id to be toggled

    var el = document.getElementById(obj);

    if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) { //if display of element is block
        el.style.display = 'none'; // sets to none
    } else {
        el.style.display = ''; //sets null or block
    }

}
```

Just check http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/

Comment: in your example, obj is not the element to be toggled, but an id of the element being toggled.

Comment: Changed in my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
var status = el.style.display;
if(status=='none'){
    el.style.display = 'block';
}else{
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

}

Comment: why do you need to relookup the element every time?

Answer (score 0):

Toggling ternary-style:

```
function toggle(objId) { // Pass the id of the object to be toggled

    // Get the element
    var el = document.getElementById(objId);

    // Toggle the style-display
    el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but here is the simple example:

Here is html

```
<li class="foo" style="display:none">List item</li>
<li class="foo" style="display:none">List item</li>
<li class="foo" style="display:none">List item</li>
<li class="foo" style="display:none">List item</li>
<li class="foo" style="display:none">List item</li>
<li class="foo" style="display:none">List item</li>
```

Here is the toggle script:

```
  <script language="javascript">
  function toggle (className) { 
  _ref = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      el = _ref[_i];
      if (el.style.display === 'block') {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          el.style.display = 'block';
      }
  }
  }
</script>
```